# Create different objects inside map with ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create two objects inside map based on a condition.
Meaning that if item.title === "something" ? {object structure 1} : {object structure 2}

What I have so far is this:

```
  function prepareColumns() {
    let columns = apiData.columns

    const newColumns = columns.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      field: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase(),
    }))
    return newColumns
  }
```

What I am to do is this:

```
  function prepareColumns() {
    let columns = apiData.columns

    const newColumns = columns.map(item => ({
      (item.title === something) ?
      ...item,
      field: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase(),
      lookup: {1: '1', 2: '2'}
      :
      ...item,
      field: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase(),
    }))
    return newColumns
  }
```

The item I am working on is coming as an array if objects and I am mapping them.

[image]

so depending on the value of the title field I will add an extra property to the object.
So far I have tried with ternary and if-else but they do not work.

Anyone know if this possible and how to achieve it?

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail what "they do not work" means? Please try to provide some sample input and example expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I see in your two objet is the lookup key which is missing in one of the two. I suggest you this syntax:

```
{
 ...item,
 field: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase(),
 ...(item.title === 'something' ? { lookup: {1: '1', 2: '2'} } : null),
}
```

The spread operator will spread an object with lookup if condition is filled, otherwise it will spread on null, resulting on not creating anything new to your object.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks a lot Julien!

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
function prepareColumns() {
  let columns = apiData.columns

  const newColumns = columns.map(item =>
    item.title === something ?
      {
        ...item,
        field: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase(),
        lookup: { 1: '1', 2: '2' }
      }

      :
      {
        ...item,
        field: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase(),
      }

  )
  return newColumns
}
```